# Show traces on mac terminal

Tags: macos, haxe, atom-editor

I'm trying to use the Atom IDE to make some Haxe project on my new Mac (as a Windows user, I'm discovering this world), and I install the package "haxe" to do this. Until there, all is perfect (great jobs to them \o/), and I can compile an swf :).

But I have a little problem, even with the "-debug", all my traces are in the swf, not on the output console (terminal if I run from it, or output panel on Atom). Maybe I've forget to do/install/init something ?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible (easily). The trace function does print to a haxe log, which is something haxe sets up in its swf outputs. However, AFAIK there is no communication between the swf and the terminal / IDE / anything else, because the swf is run separately using Flash Player. I had some mild success piping the output log of Flash Player Debugger to a terminal. The easiest way I can think of this working would be to create a custom Logger class that you include in your swf projects, then log with that. It would then connect to a listener in your terminal (netcat?) via localhost.

Comment: I see. Since my message, I did some research, and on Windows, I'm completely dependant of FlashDevelop, which integer FDB (flash debugger). So I succeed to run fdb and show the traces on my terminal. Now I just have to do a process which will do this automaticaly at the compile/run :)

Comment: Ah, forgot about fdb. For my own workflow, I created a utility command 'rx' which runs `haxe make.hxml`, then, if it finds certain strings within that file, like `-swf …`, it opens the output (using a simple `open …`). // However, I know that .hxml files allow the `-cmd` option, which should allow you to just run the fdb there.

Comment: Yep, I succeed to open fdb in the hxml (-cmd bash .sh -> a script shell which execute fdb), but, and it's rather a question of unix (where I'm new !), how can I pass parameters from the terminal to "(fdb)" (which is running) like, at least, "continue" ?

Comment: I am not sure about your specific workflow. You said it's Atom, does it allow you to interact with the executed shell script? If not, then sending the right commands at the right time might be unnecessarily complicated. Consider removing the middle-ware (Atom IDE) and using it only as the code editor. Then you can run fdb in a terminal where you can easily interact with it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, you're right ! I use Atom as an simply code editor. In fact, I thought there are a way to build, run and launch fdb easily, but I think I'll do my own workflow :). Thank you for your help !